# Undefined error thrown at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

*I see the link about the use of `this` is jQuery. Yes, the problem was exactly this, but this situation is a completely different one, so please remove useless links to other questions and mark as duplicated because this can lead to confusion to a poor SO user looking for a more simple situation.*

*Also: my code is fully pasted here, not just a snippet, and my code is not using some complicated binding at all, is more basilar. So it's a complete new question for me*

This is my **full working** code

```
var game = {
    status : {
        NOT_INITIALIZED : "gamepad:not_initialized",
        INITIALIZED     : "gamepad:initialized",
    },
    _selector : null,
    _status   : null,
    init : function( gamepad_selector ) {
        this._selector = gamepad_selector;
        $(this._selector).on(this.status.NOT_INITIALIZED, this.onNotInitialized);
        this.setState(this.status.NOT_INITIALIZED); // just to force the first console log
        $(this._selector).on(this.status.INITIALIZED, this.onInitialized);
        this.setState(this.status.INITIALIZED);
    },
    setState : function ( new_status ) {
        this._status = new_status;
        $(this._selector).trigger(new_status);
    },
    onNotInitialized: function () {
        console.log("onNotInitialized()");
    },
    onInitialized: function () {
        console.log("onInitialized()");
    },
}
```

The entry point is a call to `game.init()`.

Note that on the `init` function, I can call `setState` using one of the predefined status. This works.

```
this.setState(this.status.NOT_INITIALIZED);
```

I tried to avoid using of `this.setState`, so I deleted this function and tried to set `this._state` directly into the event listeners.

This the significative parts of **not working** code:

```
init : function( gamepad_selector ) {
    ....
    console.log ("a");
    $(this._selector).on(this.status.NOT_INITIALIZED, this.onNotInitialized);
    console.log ("b");
    $(this._selector).trigger(this.status.NOT_INITIALIZED)
    console.log ("c");
    ....
},

onNotInitialized: function () {
    // I can't do this: throws an error
    this._status = this.status.NOT_INITIALIZED;
    console.log("onNotInitialized()");
},
```

**The problem:** at runtime I got this error:

```
Cannot read property 'NOT_INITIALIZED' of undefined
```

related to

```
this._status = this.status.NOT_INITIALIZED;
```

The error is at runtime, not at 'compile' time (please forgive me the term), because I can see on the console log both `a` and `b`. But not `c`.

Why can I explicitly use `this.status.NOT_INITIALIZED` in `init` but not in `onNotInitialized` ?

Comment: Try `console.log(this)` inside the onNotInitialized function.

Comment: There's no Compile Time in JavaScript. :)

Comment: @Juhana: you're right! I forgot that `this` in a event listenere is referred to the html element involved in the event. But please, remove the "Mark as duplicated", because this is a 'real world example' of a situation about using `this` with jQuery, but the question you point to is more generalistic.

Comment: Why  Iam not able to reproduce your error !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is to do with the way JavaScript binds the `this` variable - the full rules are [quite complex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), but the reason your code fails is that when you invoke the `onNotInitialized` method via the jQuery `on()` method `this` is not bound to your `game` object but to the element that triggered the event.

You can fix the issue by using the [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function as follows:

```
$(this._selector).on(this.status.NOT_INITIALIZED, this.onNotInitialized.bind(this));
```

Comment: This is a solution, but not a good idea, I think. I prefer modify the code to access to `game.status. ....` and AVOID to modifiy the `this` pointer